# Error ORA-12520 for connecting to an Oracle data source in weblogic

Tags: oracle, weblogic

I am trying to create a datasource in weblogic, but an error occurs when clicking the "Test Configuration" button

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12520, TNS:listener could not find available handler for requested type of server...
```

this error usually occurs when the number of connections is exhausted, but if I try to connect to the database via Intelege Idea, no matter how many times I connect, it is always successful. What could be the reason for this error?